# Для чего нужен train_test_split в sklearn?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Сейчас занимаюсь машинным обучением, может кто подробно рассказать, для чего в МО нужны X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test, аргументы, которые мы получаем в результате функции train_test_split() ?

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
```

И каким образом задается параметр test_size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таким образом вы делите свою выборку на тренировочную и тестовую часть. Обучение будет происходит на тренировочной выборке, а на тестовой - проверка полученных "знаний". test_size используется для разбиения выборки(в вашем случае будет 20% использовано на тесты).

Comment: А как формируется тренировочная и тестовая часть?

Comment: Вы сами их формируете, разбивая выборку.